# can't center my nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for my nav bar and can't seem to center it on the website. What am I doing wrong? Removing float: left does nothing for positioning.
Thanks.

css

```css
ul#list-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 800px;
}

ul#list-nav li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#list-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #485e49;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
    background: #a2b3a1;
    color: #000
}
```

html

```html
</head>
<body>
    <div id="as">
        <ul id="list-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already centered, it's just that you are using explicit width for your menu so consider decreasing your menu width

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTf8h/)

CSS

```
ul#list-nav {
  list-style:none;
  margin:20px auto;
  padding:0px;
  width:800px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Currently I've made it `205px`

CSS

```
ul#list-nav {
  list-style:none;
  margin:20px auto;
  padding:0px;
  width:205px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Fixed demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTf8h/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add display: block;

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your nav bar in a wrapper div and then set the margin of that div to auto like so:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
 margin: auto;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper"> 

<!-- (your nav bar code here) -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe following should do the trick;

<div id="as" align="center">